# How to grant permissions on a multi-folder file-server

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, file-permissions, windows-server-2012-r2

I have been given the task to restructure a file server (CIFS), which is mapped to a Windows Server. Further I need to manage the file server as picture below.

[image: File server structure]

I need some guidance to know what kind of permissions I need to give and till what level should I control the permissions?

- When to use NTFS permissions?
- When to use Share permissions?
- Should I use AD Groups to manage the permissions?
- How can I reduce the effort granting permissions?
- How to deny groups access to certain folder?
- Which permissions do I use NTFS/Share?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do and the kind of permission/security scheme you come up with. See also [Share and NTFS Permissions on a File Server TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754178(v=ws.11).aspx).

Comment: its a central file share/server for organization, so the permissions change at each level

Comment: Did you read the article I linked? It would still depend on the decisions you make. If it's just one central share you will only be using the Share permissions for that one share. Which means that for anything else you will need to use NTFS permissions. Whenever you use groups or users will depend on the decisions you make and the requirements. Usually it's a good idea to use groups as you don't need to change the NTFS permissions later on but rather group memberships.